# How would I modify the logic of the List View Webpart such that it would skip a record meeting certain conditions?

Tags: 2007, list-view-web-part

I have been looking for a way to display the Group By headers of a ListView or DataView web part for those groups that are empty. It seems that as no record is set forth to parse, the empty Group Header is not available to display. It would seem to me that I would then need to include at least one record in each group to get the header to display. I would like to not have this 'special' record appear in ListView. Where might I insert a test against the 'special' case record and have it skip rendering the record in question and then continue along in the rendering loop? Is there an easier way to meet this same goal?

Answer (score 0):

You would apply a filter to the list view (Modify this view, scroll down to the filter section) so that items are omitted and set the group by field to be whatever you want to group on

Comment: If I filter out the data such that the group is empty, I don't get a group header. As I have been looking at this, it seems the header is drawn from the data passed to the page to parse. If no data exists with the column data, that column cannot be used to make a group header. I need to pass information with the group header title, but not render the given line.